# Offline PDF-to-flipbook software with bookshelf feature?

Tags: windows, offline, document-converter

Could someone recommend an offline PDF-to-flipbook program, preferably for Windows, MacOS, Android and iOS but at a minimum just for Windows, that

- converts multipage PDFs into flipbooks in .exe format, and
- creates a "bookshelf" or "bookcase", such that when you run one of the .exe files you can see an arrangement of all of the flipbooks you have created, and then you can select one and open it. Presumably you would have to put all of these into the same directory. Alternatively there could be only a single .exe which is the bookcase itself, and when you create a new flipbook as an .exe you drop it onto the bookcase and it disappears as its own separate file. The main thing that matters is that I get an offline bookcase that shows and allows access to all of the flipbooks created.

So far I have looked at the following programs, none of which are suitable:

1. 1stFlip Flipbook Creator
2. Flip Book Maker for PDF
3. Flip PDF
4. PDF to Flipbook
5. Pub HTML5
6. FlippingBook Publisher
7. 3D PageFlip
8. Flip Creator

I should add just to make this absolutely clear: I need a program that both creates and allows access to what it has created *offline*, and which therefore does not require anything to do with websites or the cloud, although of course it may *also* have such functionality.

Comment: Even before we get to the issue of a bookshelf, I'm not sure that a PDF-to-flipbook program even exists for Android or iOS that allows non-techie users (not experienced at downloading entire websites locally) to read the flipbooks offline. Such a prog would be useful though. Phones aren't big enough in my opinion to display two-page-spread flipbooks nicely, but tablets are. I will ask an Android-specific question on the appropriate SE.

Comment: Related questions for [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232489/a-program-converting-pdfs-to-flipbooks-in-apk-format-readable-on-android-wholly) and [iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410243/a-program-converting-pdfs-to-flipbooks-in-standalone-format-readable-on-ios-whol).